# Unable to process foreach binding, wait for ajax result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I am new to knockout and I have the following issue.

**Model:**

```
function AdListModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.Ads = ko.observableArray([]);
  this.addSome = function() {

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '/Home/GetAllAds',
      data: { startPosition: 0, numberOfItems: 10},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        self.Ads.push(data);

      },
      error: function(err) {
        alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
      }
    });
  };

  this.addSome();
}


// The custom binding (code below) is for dynamic data loading on scroll event (like posts in facebook)

ko.bindingHandlers.scroll = {
  updating: true,

  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var self = this;
    self.updating = true;
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
      $(window).off("scroll.ko.scrollHandler");
      self.updating = false;
    });
  },




  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var props = allBindingsAccessor().scrollOptions;
    var offset = props.offset ? props.offset : "0";
    var loadFunc = props.loadFunc;
    var load = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    var self = this;




    if (load) {
      element.style.display = "";
      $(window).on("scroll.ko.scrollHandler", function() {
        if (($(document).height() - offset <= $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
          if (self.updating) {
            loadFunc();
            self.updating = false;
          }
        } else {
          self.updating = true;
        }
      });
    } else {
      element.style.display = "none";
      $(window).off("scroll.ko.scrollHandler");
      self.updating = false;
    }
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(new AdListModel());
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-lg-12" data-bind="foreach: Ads">
// some code
</div>
<div data-bind="scroll: Ads().length < 50, scrollOptions: { loadFunc: addSome, offset: 10 }">loading</div>
```

So, initially AJAX loads 10 records from database and it renders perfectly fine.  Then if I scroll down, it is supposed to add, push to my observable array another 10 (same records). It works If I add dummy data (without database) to AJAX SUCCESS, BUT if I want to push ajax result to observable array it gives me an error "Unable to process binding". 
I understand that ajax is async and it needs some time to load date and at the time of rendering there is no data, but I don't know what to do. I need to wait for ajax, but how... or it could be another issue. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the code appending new items to `self.Ads` on scroll?

Comment: sorry, just updated.

Comment: The only potential issue I see so far is where you call `loadFunc(); self.updating = false;`. Here you probably meant to switch `self.updating` to `false` after getting ajax response but this will happen immediately, before ajax ends execution. You should rather move it to ajax response callback. Not sure if that is related to the problem.

Comment: `push` adds one element to an array. If you are trying to add 10 elements, you are doing it wrong.